# Solve the recurrence relation given by: $A_{n+2} + 4A_n = 0; A_0 = A_1 = 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am having trouble coming up with the general solution. It seems to be given by: x<sup>2</sup> + 4, but if this is the case I don't see how the problem can be solved with real numbers. Thanks for any advice or guidance in advance.

Comment: Is this $A_{n+2} + 4 A_n = 0$? If so then $A_{n+4} = -4A_{n+2} = 16A_{n}$, and you get smth like $A_{4n} = A_{4n+1} = 16^n = 4^{2n}$, $A_{4n+2} = A_{4n+3} = -4^{2n+1}$ by induction on $n$ with step $4$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Or do you want to have a way to solve linear recurrence relations of any depth? It appears to me that [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) has a good enough explanation of the general method, give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach I think you got it backwards. Notice that the polynomial is $4x^2+x+1,$ you have to take care of the initial conditions so you get that if $A=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}A_nx^n,$ then
$$A=1+x-4x^2A,$$
so $$A=\frac{1+x}{1+4x^2}=(1+x)\cdot\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}(-4)^nx^{2n}=\cdot\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}(-4)^nx^{2n}+\cdot\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}(-4^n)x^{2n+1}$$
so gives you that $A_{2n}=A_{2n+1}=(-4)^n.$

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am confused where the extra x term comes from in your first equation. Is this simply to fill in the polynomial?

Comment: @RichardMcCormick You are welcome, It comes from the initial condition $A_1=1$ so the therm $A_1x=x.$

Answer (score 0):

$$A_{n+2}=-4A_n$$
Let $A_n=t^n$, then $t=\pm 2 i \implies A_n =C(2i)^n+D (-2i)^n=2^n [ C  e^{in\pi/2}+D e^{-i n\pi/2}]$
$$A_0=0 \implies A_0=C+D=1 ~ \text{and}~A_1=C-D=-i/2 \implies C=(1/2-i/4), D=(1/2+i/4)$$
So $$A_n=2^n[(1/2-i/4)e^{in\pi/2}+(1/2+i/4)e^{i\pi n/2}]=2^{n} [\cos(n\pi/2)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(n\pi/2)]$$

Comment: OP has $A_{n+2}=-4A_n$, not $A_{n+2}=4A_n$.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it, you may see.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove by induction $A_{2n}=A_{2n+1}=(-4)^n$, i.e. $A_n=(-4)^{\left\lfloor\tfrac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}$.